# Halt React from rendering/clearing state of a view until animations/callback is complete?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, reactjs

So i've got a react app using react router. The router hooks up to a nav that updates the same component view for 4 different routes - `2012, 2013, 2014, 2015`. Each route triggers an API call that pulls in some JSON, and the component is re-rendered with the new `state.data`.

What i'd like to do is be able to fade out the view, then call the API, then fade in the new view with the new `state.data`.

The issue i have at the moment, is the view is rendering blank before it has time to fade out, then the new data is pulled in, and the fade in transition is triggered once the data is loaded.

Are there any hooks i can tap into that'll stop the `this.state.data` clearing before view has faded out?

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React  = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Reqwest = require('reqwest');

var StreamItem = require('./StreamItem.jsx');

var Stream = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ Router.State ],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: null
    }
  },

  readFromAPI: function(url, successFunction) {
    Reqwest({
      url: url,
      type: 'json',
      method: 'get',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: successFunction,
      error: function(error) {
        console.error(url, error['response']);
        location = '/';
      }
    });
    console.log('read api called');
  },

  componentWillMount: function () {
    this.readTweetsFromAPI();
  },

  readTweetsFromAPI: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.readFromAPI(this.getPath(), function(tweets) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        self.setState({
          data: tweets
        });
        // state of page transitions is kept a level up to include
        // other components. This function toggles a boolean to true,         
        // which toggles a css class transition on the parent 
        // component.
        self.props.fadeInPage();
      }, 500);

    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    if (this.state.data) {
      var tweetItems = this.state.data.map(function(tweet, index) {
        return <StreamItem key={tweet.id} tweet={tweet}/>
      }.bind(this));
    }

    return (
      <div className="tweet-list__archive">
        {tweetItems}
      </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Stream;
```

Comment: Can you show us your component source code

Comment: Added the source for the component.

Comment: I recommend you to let component handle fade in/out itself. There you can you React's CssTransitionGroup https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html. I correctly handles CSS animations

Comment: Ah, interesting. I had a play with this before, but didn't get far. I'll spend some proper time with it and see if i can the effect i'm looking for. Cheers man.